# Как отследить готовность программы к работе с ней?

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Я произвожу запуск *.exe из приложения на c#. Мне необходимо понять, когда *.exe закончит запуск и будет готова для работы с ней.

**Пояснительная записка**

Что я имею ввиду?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно понять, когда это окошко исчезнет, и word(или любая другая программа) будет готов для работы с документами. Заранее благодарю! Если не трудно, то посоветуйте заодно литературу к прочтению!

Comment: "например" по большому счету нельзя, точно отследить можно только для конкретного приложения, скорее всего с помощью WinAPI попытаться найти окно по тексту заголовка или wndclass, если есть = готово. а зачем вообще нужно?

Comment: Можно использовать [process.WaitForInputIdle();](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21275996)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, что планируется делать с программой.
Если вы хотите автоматизировать какие-то действия в c#, то можно воспользоваться приемом неявного ожидания.

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    try
    {
        Действия с программой...
        break;
    }
    catch
    { 
        Задержка на n секунд
    }
}
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток, Юрий. После полной загрузки приложения я хотел, чтобы программа меня об этом уведомляла: программа готова к работе и всё такое)